# Why does the operation in python `multiprocessing` not take effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

A = []

def appendNum(i):
    print(f"append {i}")
    A.append(i)
    print(A)

def batchAppend():
    p = Pool(10)
    p.map(appendNum, range(10))
    p.close()
    p.join()

    print("Appending finished.")
    print("A = ", A)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    batchAppend()
```

I want to append some numbers to an array using multiprocessing.

Every time when `appendNum` method executes and I print the array, there is only one number in the array.

In the end I print the array again, and this time there is not even a single element in the array.

I don't quit understand:

1. Why is there only one number in the array when `appendNum` method executes every time?  Is it because pool size = 10? If the pool size < 10, sometimes the array may contain more than one element.
2. Why is there nothing in the array in the end?

Comment: Each process has ***it's own*** copy of `A`... It is not a global shared list between all of them. This is why each print has one number and why the final one is empty (no one is appending to the main one)

Comment: See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: you can still enable the list creation by introducing a lock in the appendnum function (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) This does not alter the original content of A, but fixes the "one or sometimes more"-issue, which is happening due to a race condition.